# Python Backpropagation: No output value

Tags: python, connection, neural-network, backpropagation

so I'm trying to work on back propagation right now but for some reason, I'm getting an output, an activation, but nothing for the output value. Right now I'm just working with a one layer network, just something simple but it doesn't seem to do what it's suppose to.

I've created 2 sets of nodes, node1 and node2, added connections connecting 1 to 2. Trained it on the patterns below, updated weight, update input, update activation, then output. But I get 0's.

```
# 
#                               Preparations 
# 

import random
import math
import pygame
import sys
node1 = []
node2 = []
node3 = []
node4 = []
node5 = []
set1 = []
set2 = []
set3 = []
NUMNODES = 10
mu = .5
eta = .1

# 
#                                   Node Class
# 

class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self,name=None): 
        self.name=name 
        self.activation_threshold=0.0
        self.net_input=0.0
        self.net_output=0.0
        self.outgoing_connections=[] 
        self.incoming_connections=[]
        self.activation=None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def addconnection(self,sender,weight=0.0):
        self.incoming_connections.append(Connection(sender,self,weight))
        self.outgoing_connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight)) 

    def update_input(self): 
        self.net_input=0.0
        for conn in self.incoming_connections: 
            self.net_input += conn.weight * conn.sender.activation
##        print 'Input for node', str(self), 'is', self.net_input


############################# Is this necessary? ####################
    def update_output(self): 
        self.net_output=0.0
        for conn in self.outgoing_connections: 
            self.net_output += conn.weight * self.activation
###########################################################################

    def update_activation(self):
        if self.net_input > self.activation_threshold:
            self.activation = 1.0
        else:
            self.activation = 0.0
##        print 'Activation :', self.activation
##    def update_weight(self):
##        for i in self.incoming_connections:
##            i.weight += self.delta_wt
##            self.delta_wt = mu
    def update_weight(self):
        for i in self.incoming_connections:
            i.weight += (2*i.reciever.activation - 1)*(2*i.sender.activation-1)
##            print 'Weight of', str(i.reciever), 'to', str(i.sender), 'is', i.weight

    def update_error(self):
        pass

# 
#                                   Connection Class
# 

class Connection(object): 
    def __init__(self, sender, reciever, weight): 
        self.weight=weight 
        self.sender=sender 
        self.reciever=reciever

    def __str__(self):
        string = "Connection from " + str(self.sender) + " to " + str(self.reciever) + ", weight = " + str(self.weight)
        return string

#######################################################################################
# 
#                                     Creating Nodes & Connections 
# 
#######################################################################################

def set_activations(act_vector): 
    for i in xrange(len(act_vector)): 
        node1[i].activation = act_vector[i]
        node2[i].activation = act_vector[i]

for i in xrange(NUMNODES): 
    node1.append(Node(str(i)))
    node2.append(Node(str(i)))
    node3.append(Node(str(i)))
    node4.append(Node(str(i)))
    node5.append(Node(str(i)))

for i in xrange(NUMNODES):
    for j in xrange(NUMNODES):
        if i!=j:
            node1[i].addconnection(node2[j])
            node3[i].addconnection(node4[j])
            node4[i].addconnection(node5[j])


#######################################################################################
#
#                                         Training Patterns
#
#######################################################################################

"""Non-Overlapping Categories"""
cata11=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(cata11)
cata12=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
set1.append(cata12)
catb11=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]
set1.append(catb11)
catb12=[0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catb12)
catc11=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catc11)
catc12=[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catc12)
catd11=[0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catd11)
catd12=[1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set1.append(catd12)
"""Linearly Independent Instances and Linearly Separable Categories"""
cata21=[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
set2.append(cata21)
cata22=[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]
set2.append(cata22)
catb21=[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]
set2.append(catb21)
catb22=[1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]
set2.append(catb22)
catc21=[1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catc21)
catc22=[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catc22)
catd21=[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catd21)
catd22=[1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set2.append(catd22)

"""Not Linearly Separable Categories"""
cata31=[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
set3.append(cata31)
cata32=[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
set3.append(cata32)
catb31=[1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
set3.append(catb31)
catb32=[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]
set3.append(catb32)

set_activations(cata11)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(cata12)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(catb11)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(catb12)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(catc11)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(catc12)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(catd11)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()
set_activations(catd12)
for thing in node1:
    thing.update_weight()

#######################################################################################
#
#                                        Updating Network
#
#######################################################################################

for i in node1:
    i.update_input()
    print 'Node', str(i), 'Input : ', i.net_input
    i.update_activation()
    print 'Act:', i.activation
    i.update_output()
    print 'Output', i.net_output

out_file=open('output.txt','w')
out_file.close()
```

Comment: If you have a zillion variables ending in consecutive numbers, like `cata31`, `cata32`, you should start thinking about data structures.

Comment: @OP why do you open an output file and then just close it?